# Adalight program exported from Processing 2.2.1 not running

Tags: windows, export, processing

Alright, here's hopefully my last question about a problem I'm having with my Adalight setup.  Anyway, Processing exports two folders, application.windows32, and application.widows64, both of them have a adalight.exe file inside of them, along with lib, and source folders.  When I try to run the adalight.exe file, nothing happens, nothing loads, no windows show up, there's no error message.  I don't know if it's a problem with my PC, the Processing IDE, or my code (works perfectly if ran through the IDE).  I'm not sure if this is enough information, if you need any more I'd be happy to try to provide as much as I can.

Comment: Try to run it from `cmd` to do so open command line in directory where is located you exported application and just type `adalight.exe` and hit enter ... maybe it will display some more information.

Comment: Nope, it nothing happens, then it goes back to the directory and waits for another command. ![Command Line](http://i.imgur.com/S6mg3ie.png)

Comment: So try export some very basic adalight app ... just window with "hello world" and if this wont't work the should be problem with processing export functionality. But if it works problem could be in your implementation.